# Clear Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin

I create first chart using bitmap and canvas. How I can clear bitmap for drawing new chart?

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
...
imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
relativeLayout.AddView(imageView);
```

Comment: can you try invalidate()?

Comment: you should get a full black bitmap. Are you getting something else?

Comment: The method bitmap.Invalidate() no exists

Comment: My bitmap is transparent at first. After I draw first chart. After I want to make my bitmap transparent again (without chart).

Comment: No! Bitmap mustn't be NULL. I want clear my bitmap without recreating and use it again.

Comment: so setting bitmap to transparent ? `bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: Thanks. bitmap.eraseColor is answer

Comment: @user3707143 I have put the accepted comment as an answer so it can help others in future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // Your Other code
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
relativeLayout.AddView(imageView);
```

**Now release memory of bitmap by below code**

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

**Help** of **recycle()** method of **bitmap** as per [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).

public void recycle () 
Added in API level 1
Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the reference to the pixel data. This will not free the pixel data synchronously; it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there are no other references. The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it will throw an exception if getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and will draw nothing. This operation cannot be reversed, so it should only be called if you are sure there are no further uses for the bitmap. This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more references to this bitmap.

Comment: If I will write bitmap.recycle(), I can't use bitmap again. I must re create bitmap?

Comment: @user3707143, yes exactly. if you write bitmap.recycle() then it will release memory of bitmap, if you want to use again you have to create new one.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean "normal GC process will free up this memory"?

Comment: @user3707143 Normal GC process will release memory of objects which are not in use in current state.

Comment: I wrote: bitmap.recycle(); bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(...) and I got overflow of memory. I can't create new bitmap, only clear old

Comment: @user3707143 what code you wrote for create bitmap ? Can you please show me ?

Comment: bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(6000, 800, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);

Comment: bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(600, 800, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888); try using 600 instead of 6000.

Answer (score 37):

You can use `eraseColor` on bitmap to set its color to Transparent. It will useable again without recreating it.

```
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Further reading [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#eraseColor%28int%29)

Comment: Best way to reuse a bitmap that doesn't get created/managed by BitmapFactory

Comment: cleanest solution.

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to use

```
bitmap.eraseColor
```